# How to broadcast a matrix within a vector in Julia?

Tags: julia, broadcast

The variables "xs" and "ys" are defined as 2-element vectors of two matrices with size (2, 3) as below.

```
xs = [rand(2, 3) for _ in 1:2]
ys = [rand(2, 3) for _ in 1:2]
```

I want to check the sum of the squared differences of xs and ys for each element in a vector.

For example, let's say I have

```
xs[1] = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
xs[2] = [0 1 2; 2 1 0]
ys[1] = [0 0 1; 0 0 2]
ys[2] = [1 0 0; 0 0 1]
```

I can do this with below:

```
if sum((xs[1] .- ys[1]).^2) < 0
if sum((xs[2] .- ys[2]).^2) < 0
```

But I want to check the following for both i = 1 and i = 2:

`sum((xs[i] .- ys[i]).^2) < 0`

How can I do this at once in the if statement?

I get an error by trying the following:

```
if all(sum((xs .- ys).^2) < 0
```

Comment: How would you expect that _sum of the squared differences_ could be smaller than zero? Is it a typo or just a contrived hypothetical example?

Comment: oops, yes a hypothetical example! the right side can be anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One way is to use the [`map`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.map) function:

```
julia> x = [[1 2 3; 4 5 6], [0 1 2; 2 1 0]]
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
 [0 1 2; 2 1 0]

julia> y = [[0 0 1; 0 0 2], [1 0 0; 0 0 1]]
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [0 0 1; 0 0 2]
 [1 0 0; 0 0 1]

julia> all(map((a, b)->sum((a.-b).^2)<0, x, y))
false
```

For the lazy version of the `map`, you can use [`Iterators.map`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.map) instead:

```
julia> all(Iterators.map((a, b)->sum((a.-b).^2)<0, x, y))
false
```

2. Another way is to use a combination of zipping and comprehension:

```
julia> all([sum((a.-b).^2)<0 for (a, b) in zip(x, y)])
false
```

Also, you can utilize the lazy version of the `zip` using `Iterators.zip`:

```
julia> all([sum((a.-b).^2)<0 for (a, b) in Iterators.zip(x, y)])
false
```

3. As [dear Bogumił suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74648468/how-to-broadcast-a-matrix-within-a-vector-in-julia#comment131761675_74648571), You can pass the anonymous function directly to the [`all` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.all-Tuple%7BAbstractArray,%20Any%7D) like this:

```
julia> all(a->sum((a[1].-a[2]).^2)<0, zip(x, y))
false
```

---

#### Your code:

> I get an error by trying the following:
> `if all(sum((xs .- ys).^2) < 0`

Let's dissect this piece of code and investigate it. One of the main problems with your code is that you're trying to perform broadcasting directly on two vectors that contain two matrixes:

```
julia> (xs .- ys).^2
ERROR
```

This is similar to something like expecting nested broadcasting. For this approach, you should perform a *broadcast broadcast*. Considering the `x` and `y` which I defined before:

```
julia> broad_broad = broadcast.((a, b)->sum((a - b)^2), x, y)
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 4 4; 16 25 16]
 [1 1 4; 4 1 1]
```

And then, calculate the sum of each component of `broad_broad` using another broadcasting:

```
julia> sum.(broad_broad)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 66
 12
```

Then, you can pass it to the `all` function:

```
julia> all(x->x<0, sum.(broad_broad))
false
```

I don't recommend you to do this. But I tried to help you a little bit to understand where your mistake was.

Comment: `all` also can take a function as a first argument so you can pass `zip(x, y)` to it.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, Thanks, dear professor! I added your suggestion!